# Windows API Declarations For Compatibility

Tags: vba, winapi

This is an extension of my [Reusable Progress Indicator](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/223581/reusable-progress-indicator) post. I realised that I needed to add additional compiler constants for compatibility of the Windows API functions used in the `HideTitleBar` sub which is called on the `Userform_Initialize` event; however, I am unsure if they are correct for all cases. I have tested the code on Windows 64-Bit for both 32-Bit Excel and 64-Bit Excel and it worked without issue, but because I have no access to Win 32-Bit OS, I can't really test if my declarations have the correct keywords and data types for that case.

So with that I ask, are my declarations correct and is the setup of the API declarations the most general/comprehensive method?

```
#If Win64 And VBA7 Then  '64-Bit Windows and 64-Bit Excel


    Private Declare PtrSafe Function GetWindowLong _
                           Lib "user32" Alias "GetWindowLongA" ( _
                           ByVal hwnd As LongPtr, _
                           ByVal nIndex As LongPtr) As LongPtr
    Private Declare PtrSafe Function SetWindowLong _
                           Lib "user32" Alias "SetWindowLongA" ( _
                           ByVal hwnd As LongPtr, _
                           ByVal nIndex As LongPtr, _
                           ByVal dwNewLong As LongPtr) As LongPtr

    Private Declare PtrSafe Function DrawMenuBar _
                           Lib "user32" ( _
                           ByVal hwnd As LongPtr) As LongPtr
    Private Declare PtrSafe Function FindWindowA _
                           Lib "user32" (ByVal lpClassName As String, _
                           ByVal lpWindowName As String) As LongPtr

    Private Declare PtrSafe Function GetTickCount _
                            Lib "kernel32.dll" () As LongPtr


#ElseIf Win64 And Not VBA7 Then '64-Bit Windows and 32-Bit Excel

    Private Declare PtrSafe Function GetWindowLong _
                            Lib "user32" Alias "GetWindowLongA" ( _
                            ByVal hwnd As Long, _
                            ByVal nIndex As Long) As Long
    Private Declare PtrSafe Function SetWindowLong _
                            Lib "user32" Alias "SetWindowLongA" ( _
                            ByVal hwnd As Long, _
                            ByVal nIndex As Long, _
                            ByVal dwNewLong As Long) As Long
    Private Declare PtrSafe Function DrawMenuBar _
                            Lib "user32" ( _
                            ByVal hwnd As Long) As Long
    Private Declare PtrSafe Function FindWindowA _
                            Lib "user32" (ByVal lpClassName As String, _
                            ByVal lpWindowName As String) As Long

    Private Declare PtrSafe Function GetTickCount _
                            Lib "kernel32.dll" () As Long


#Else '32-Bit Windows and 32-Bit Excel

    Private Declare Function GetWindowLong _
                            Lib "user32" Alias "GetWindowLongA" ( _
                            ByVal hwnd As Long, _
                            ByVal nIndex As Long) As Long
    Private Declare Function SetWindowLong _
                            Lib "user32" Alias "SetWindowLongA" ( _
                            ByVal hwnd As Long, _
                            ByVal nIndex As Long, _
                            ByVal dwNewLong As Long) As Long
    Private Declare Function DrawMenuBar _
                            Lib "user32" ( _
                            ByVal hwnd As Long) As Long
    Private Declare Function FindWindowA _
                            Lib "user32" (ByVal lpClassName As String, _
                            ByVal lpWindowName As String) As Long

    Private Declare Function GetTickCount _
                            Lib "kernel32.dll" () As Long


#End If


Private Sub HideTitleBar()

 Dim lngWindow As LongPtr, lngFrmHdl As LongPtr

    lngFrmHdl = FindWindowA(vbNullString, Me.Caption)
    lngWindow = GetWindowLong(lngFrmHdl, GWL_STYLE)
    lngWindow = lngWindow And (Not WS_CAPTION)
    SetWindowLong lngFrmHdl, GWL_STYLE, lngWindow
    DrawMenuBar lngFrmHdl

End Sub
```

**Example (Please See the [Reusable Progress Indicator](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/223581/reusable-progress-indicator) post for more details):**

In frm Code:

```
Private Sub IProgressIndicator_LoadProgIndicator(Optional ByVal HasParentProccess As Boolean, _
                                                 Optional ByVal CanCancel As Boolean, _
                                                 Optional ByVal CalculateExecutionTime As Boolean)

    this.CalculateExecutionTime = CalculateExecutionTime

    If CalculateExecutionTime Then this.StartTime = GetTickCount()

    'CALLED HERE
    HideTitleBar

    this.HasParentProccess = HasParentProccess: this.CanCancel = CanCancel

    With Me
        If this.HasParentProccess Then
            .Height = PROGINDICATOR_MAXHEIGHT
            .ParentProcedureStatus.Height = PARENTPROCSTATUS_MAXHEIGHT
            .ProcedureStatus.Top = PROCSTATUS_MAXTOP
            .frameProgressBar.Top = PROGRESSBAR_MAXTOP

            .lblElapsedTime.Top = ELAPSEDTIME_MAXTOP
            .ElapsedTime.Top = ELAPSEDTIME_MAXTOP

            .lblTimeRemaining.Top = TIMEREMAINING_MAXTOP
            .TimeRemaining.Top = TIMEREMAINING_MAXTOP
        End If
        .ProgressBar.Width = 0
        .StartUpPosition = 0
        .Left = Application.Left + (STARTPOS_LEFT_OFFSET * Application.Width) - (STARTPOS_LEFT_OFFSET * .Width)
        .Top = Application.Top + (STARTPOS_RIGHT_OFFSET * Application.Height) - (STARTPOS_RIGHT_OFFSET * .Height)
        .Show
    End With

End Sub
```

In regular Module:

```
Public Sub TestingOrphanProccess()

 Dim i As Long
 Dim ProgressBar As IProgressIndicator

    On Error GoTo ErrHandle
    Set ProgressBar = New ProgressIndicator

    ProgressBar.LoadProgIndicator CanCancel:=True, CalculateExecutionTime:=True

        For i = 1 To 10000
            'only have to specify this property if boolCanCancel:=True
            If ProgressBar.ShouldCancel Then Exit Sub
            StaticSheet_Sht1.Cells(1, 1) = i

            ProgressBar.UpdateOrphanProgress "Proccessing", i, 10000
        Next

    Exit Sub

ErrHandle:
    Debug.Print Err.Number
End Sub
```

Comment: Your VBA7 declarations are wrong. Seems like you just replaced`Long`with`LongPtr`? Usually, you only change pointers and handles to`LongPtr`everything else stays`Long`  I use [Windows API Viewer for MS Excel](https://www.rondebruin.nl/win/dennis/windowsapiviewer.htm) to create Win-API declarations.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

IMO, you're overcomplicating it. For 99% of the cases, you only need something similar to this:

```
#If VBA7 Then
  'VBA7 declaration style
    Private Declare PtrSafe Function GetWindowLong _
                           Lib "user32" Alias "GetWindowLongA" ( _
                           ByVal hwnd As LongPtr, _
                           ByVal nIndex As Long) As Long
#Else
  'VBA6 declaration style
    Private Declare Function GetWindowLong _
                            Lib "user32" Alias "GetWindowLongA" ( _
                            ByVal hwnd As Long, _
                            ByVal nIndex As Long) As Long
#End If
```

You don't really need to check `Win64` constant solely for API compatibility. As a matter of fact, you want to prefer using VBA7 API declarations whenever possible because they align much more closely to the actual C++ declarations that the API declarations are based on.

The only reason to use `Win64`<sup>1</sup> is to do something that can be done exclusively in 64-bit Office (which is very rare and I have trouble thinking of a good example beyond simply just checking whether the Office itself is 64-bit. The single anomaly is a certain API function - `SetWindowsLongPtr` which for some reasons, doesn't have the same declarations between 32-bit Windows and 64-bit Windows OS, in which case, you do have to use `Win64` for that particular API declaration. But others, just `VBA7` is sufficient and using VBA7 declaration style means you get more information from reading the declarations than you would have had from VBA6. `hWnd As LongPtr` is abundantly obvious that it's a pointer, not just an integer like say, `nIndex As Long`.

Props to [@computerversteher](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/users/175456/computerversteher):

My original post was a blind copy'n'paste from OP to illustrate the correct situation. However, he pointed out that the declarations themselves were incorrect, in particular, the `nIndex` parameter which was originally a `LongPtr` but that is not correct since it's just an integer, not a true pointer. Only pointer data types should be assigned `LongPtr`. As per the comment:

> [How to convert Windows API declarations in VBA for 64-bit](https://codekabinett.com/rdumps.php?Lang=2&targetDoc=windows-api-declaration-vba-64-bit) provides an example for WIN64 (When to use the WIN64 compiler constant in the last third of article (sorry no anchors), that provides basic knowledge).

Thanks, @computerversteher!

---

1. Note that `Win64` is something of a misnomer. It'll be only `True` when the Office is a 64-bit install, but will be `False` even on a 64-bit Windows running 32-bit Office. For sanity's sake, pretend that various `WinXX` constants are actually named `OfficeXX`.

Comment: Interesting.  So just to clarify, my last `Else` directive is unneeded, because my second 'Else' directive, (which is a `VBA6`  declaration),  also covers `32-bit Windows` and `32-bit Excel`?

Comment: Additionally `Win64` evaluates to `True` on Mac OS 64-bit office, `False` on 32 bit (same behaviour as Windows, just even weirder thet `Win...` evaluates to true ever on a Mac).

Comment: It's actually the `#ElseIf Win64 And Not VBA7 Then` that's incorrect and unnecessary. It's incorrect because you have `PtrSafe` which is a VBA7 keyword so it wouldn't even run.

Comment: @Greedo Yep, That's why `Win...` is a bad name - It would have been much more clearer if it was `Office...` instead. Life's a bowl of cherries.

Comment: I wonder, are there any other situations where OS bitness matters - there's that one unusual declaration as you point out. But could a 32-bit Office on 64-bit Windows ever be required to use `LongLong` for pointers. I believe the application keeps its own 32-bit memory with `Long` 32-bit addresses, but what if you want to refer to the address space of some separate 64-bit application, its window handle or something? I know you sometimes require `LongLong`/`ULong` in 32-bit office for other things (`QueryPerformanceCounter` IIRC), but does a 32-bit Office ever require a `LongLong` pointer type?

Comment: The problem is that `LongLong` doesn't exist in a 32-bit Office, IIRC. You cannot actually do `Dim x As LongLong` in that case anyway. `LongPtr` on a 32-bit VBA environment maps to a `Long`. BTW, `LongLong` isn't a true pointer data type. It's just an integer. A pointer scales with the architecture, so its size isn't the same across different architectures. `Long` and `LongLong` means the same thing everywhere but `LongPtr` doesn't.

Comment: @this Yeah I just though about that a minute ago and realized, lol. So then to further clarify for my own understanding, all I need for `Windows 64-Bit` Compatibility with either '32-bit` or `64-Bit` Office, are the declarations under the  `#If Win64 And VBA7 Then` directive, (which should be changed to ` #If VBA7 Then`), and for 'Windows 32-Bit' all I need are the declarations under `#Else` directive? Because if that's the case, then what I had in my original Reusable Progress Indicator post was completely fine save the use of `LongPtr` in the calling procedure....

Comment: ...which means I made things waaayyy too complicated, lol.

Comment: Not exactly - most of time, all you care about is compatibility with VBA7 or VBA6. VBA6 never could ever run in 64-bit Office, since it never existed. VBA7 can run both on 64-bit and 32-bit Office, regardless of Windows' bitness. Since a VBA7 style declaration will run for either 64-bit or 32-bit Office, you should just use VBA7 declaration everywhere. The only reason to include a VBA6 declaration is to provide a backward compatibility for Office installs prior to 2010 (when VBA7 and 64-bit Office was introduced) since those version cannot understand VBA7's keywords like `PtrSafe` and so on.

Comment: One more thing that might help clarify the confusion. On a 32-bit Office's VBA7, you could get away with incorrectly using `Long` for where `LongPtr` would be needed because as mentioned, `LongPtr` maps to `Long`... but only on a 32-bit Office. So the declaration will apparently work... Until you try to to use the same code on a 64-bit Office, where it may blow up (or worse, works in an undefined way). Using `LongPtr` correctly will work on both 32-bit and 64-bit Offices without any change to the code, which is why using only the `VBA7` suffices for most cases.

Comment: @this Gotcha. Thanks so much for taking to the time to explain!

Comment: @rickmanalexander (@)this FWIW I've tried to collect my thoughts on the whole OS vs Office bitness confusion with [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/56937514/6609896)

Comment: @Greedo Excellent Idea! I have really started to use the API functions quite a lot lately and it is difficult to find comprehensive examples on the topic of `OS` / `Host` compatibility with respect to bitness, so I look forward to the discussion your question sparks.

Comment: Memo to myself: Actually read OP's code. You're actually correct; my post was focusing on the question about structuring the declarations, not the declarations. I've updated the post accordingly. :)

Comment: Do you think maybe op should use [`GetWindowLongPtr`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-gb/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-getwindowlongptra) which has superceded the current approach? Although op only uses the function to get a `GWL_STYLE` attribute which will fit in a `Long`, the function can also return handles or function pointers which probably need more space on 64 bit office (well window handles apparently don't, but the others may) so perhaps a `LongPtr` return value is appropriate. Not sure what conditional compilation is needed to check whether that API version exists though!